# refer from inner `with` function to higher level `with` function

Tags: kotlin

In my code I have a struct like this

```
post { req ->
    with(req.objectBody<Person>()) {
        logger.info { "Attempt to save person $this" }
        with(require<SessionFactory>().openSession()) {
            save(this@with)
        }
    }
}
```

But IDE warns me that `there is more than one label with such a name`. In this case

```
save(this@with)
```

I want to refer to `with(req.objectBody<Person>)` instance. How to achieve that?

Comment: Don't use nested `with`, use another scope function which lets you assign a name to the value you're referring to (for example `let`).

Comment: @yold something like `req.objectBody<Person>().let { with() { save(it) } }`?

Answer (score 6):

Technically, you can mark lambdas with custom labels and then use labeled this with those labels. such as:

```
with(foo()) mylabel@{
    with(bar()) {
        baz(this@mylabel)
    }
}
```

However, to improve readability, instead of `with`, you can use the `let` scoping function and provide a name for the parameter:

```
foo().let { fooResult ->
    bar().let { barResult ->
        baz(fooResult)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to hide `let` with inline function and keep `fooResult`? Something like `withBody(req) { logger.info { "Attempt to save body $body"} }`?

Comment: But `.let` is the same number of characters as `with`. Plus, it's much more readable. With the example you've provided, I don't know where `$body` comes from and I'm left to guess that it's a hidden product of the method `withBody`.